# interpolate with 2 set of data

Tags: python, graph, numpy, matplotlib, interpolation

Hi i am trying to plot a basic interpolation graph, interpolate data1 with data2 and SecondData1 with SecondData2.. But i not sure where i can put my first data set and second data set in. I been struck in this for almost a day..

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# first data set
data1 = [15000, 11000, 8000, 4000, +1000, +552, -708, -8000, -8, 10000, +15000]
data2 = [30E-06, 13E-06, 2E-06, -179E-06, -7E-06, -19E-06, -30E-06, -10E-06, -1.9E-06, 30E-06, 30E-06]
X1 = np.linspace(-15000,15000,11)
Y1 = np.sin(X1)

# second data set
SecondData1 = [10000, 4000, 447, -4000, -6000, -9000, -4000,-122, 4000, +9000, +10000]
SecondData2 = [27E-06, 28E-06, 28E-06, 27E-06, 28E-06, 30E-06, -28E-06, -27E-06, 27E-06, 29E-06, 27E-06]
X2 = np.linspace(-10000, 10000, 11)
Y2 = np.cos(X2)

# get interpolated values of Y1 evaluated at X2
Y1_interp = np.interp(X2, X1, Y1)

# plot interpolated Y1 vs Y2
plt.plot(Y1_interp, Y2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: @CTZhu i am trying to get a interpolation graph out of this 2 set of data. firstSET and secondSET -> 2 graph 2 interpolation

Comment: what do you mean with "data1 with data2" it doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @zhenhui, in your example you just define ``data1``, ``data2``, ``SecondData1``, ``SecondData2`` but you never use them. You mean you want to have data1 and SecondData1 on the same graph with ``data1`` evaluated at ``SecondData2`` and ``SecondData1`` evaluated at ``data2``? This is the only thing that makes sense to me.

Comment: @razvanc i am trying to use data1 and data2 to plot the best fit line. But i not sure where i can put my first data set and second data set in..

Comment: I am very sorry @zhenhui, I tried my best to understand what you want (plotted the data sets), but it's really difficult. You are not even using your ``data1, data2, SecondData1, SecondData2`` variables in the example... rendering them useless. You should be more clear, give as much information as possible if you want this solved.