# Interpolate data

Tags: python, graph, numpy, interpolation

Hello i am trying to obtain the following interpolate function below.

```
data1 = [15000, 11000, 8000, 4000, +1000, +552, 0, -708, -8000, -8, 10000, +15000]
data2 = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,0,3,2,1]

data1  data2
15000   10
11000    9
 8000    8
 4000    7
 1000    6
  552    5
   ..   ..
```

I tried the following Code but the graph is constant because i used line space as its step. How can i obtain the table above..

```
x = np.linspace(-15000,15000,10) 
y = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

f = interpolate.interp1d(x,y)
f2 = interpolate.interp1d(x,y,kind='linear')
xnew = np.linspace(0,10,40)
plt.plot(x,y,'o',xnew,f(xnew),'-', xnew, f2(xnew),'--')
plt.show()
```

Output shown
[image]

Comment: It seems to me a rephrasing/duplicate of the question you [asked yesterday]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555680/interpolate-with-2-set-of-data). And by the way I still don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Given the values in `data1` and `data2` the plot is correct

Comment: Where are you getting `interpolate` from?

Comment: it's [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
data1 = [15000, 11000, 8000, 4000, +1000, +552, 0, -708, -8000, -8, 10000, +15000]
data2 = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 0, 3, 2, 1]

print "{0:10}{1:10}".format("Data 1", "Data 2")
for var1, var2 in zip(data1, data2):
    print "{0:<10}{1:<10}".format(var1, var2)
```

Running [example](http://ideone.com/2zzGNM).

The above code simple combines the two lists, using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), that means, you can get both their values side by side as a tuple. To quote from the documentation:

> This function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence. When there are multiple arguments which are all of the same length, zip() is similar to map() with an initial argument of None. With a single sequence argument, it returns a list of 1-tuples. With no arguments, it returns an empty list.

Here is a console example:

```
>> zip([2,3,11,3], [5,6,77,1])
[(2, 5), (3, 6), (11, 77), (3, 1)]
```

Comment: I don't think that the OP is asking about pretty printing the values in `data1` and `data2`. She/He wants to do something and plot it, but I can't understand what. Yesterday she/he asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555680/interpolate-with-2-set-of-data)

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano You're right. I gave my answer by understanding what I knew best, but the question remains unclear to me as well. If you happen to understand _what_ she wants, do give an answer, I'll upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean `xnew = np.linspace(-15000,15000,40)`?

You interpolated and plotted everything correctly, but your interpolated x-axis ranges from 0 to 10, while your initial x-axis ranges from -15000 to 15000. Thus all of your interpolated data points are around (0,5.5). You can see a point there on your graph.